# Calculus - finite integration of $e^{y^3}$ in double integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

i have this problem that bugs me for 3 hours now. I searched the internet and did not find a solution to this specific problem which was asked in our final:

$$\int_0^3 \;\int_{\sqrt{x/3}}^r  e^{y^3}\;dy\;dx$$

i guess this is solved by polar coordinates and jacobien, but i cant seem to find an asnswer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt{x/3}$ or $\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{x}$ in the integral? What is $r$?

Comment: i mean √x/3, and i dont know what is r, radius of an circle is my best guest.

Comment: Are you certain the lower limit is not $\sqrt{x/3}$?  That simplifies things quite a bit when $r=1$.

Comment: @Dr.MV    Oh shoot, yeah it is √(x/3), i cant seem to do make it as fancy as yours but you are right, its like that. I actually mean "square root of x/3".

Answer (score 1):

Switch the order of integration.

The computation is a bit messy for a general $r$, but, by way of illustration, if we take $r=1$ we have a simple computation:
$$\int_0^3\int_{\sqrt{x/3}}^1e^{y^3}dy\,dx=\int_0^1\int_0^{3y^2}e^{y^3}dx\,dy=\int_0^13y^2e^{y^3}dy=e^{y^3}\Big|_0^1=e-1.$$
Now, try to generalize the computation to any $r$. [Hint: You will have to split the integral into two parts.]

Comment: $$\int_0^3\int_{\sqrt{x}/3}^1e^{y^3}dy\,dx= \int_0^{1/\sqrt{3}}\int_0^{9y^2}e^{y^3}dx\,dy+\int_{1/\sqrt{3}}^{1}\int_{0}^{3}e^{y^3}dxdy$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\int_0^r$ than ? Why should i split it ?


@Dr.MV I can't understand sorry but why would it be 0 -> 1/√3 and 1/√3 -> 1

Comment: @Deniz I was correcting Spenser's change of integration order.

Comment: @Dr.MV since spenser did not answer, can you please say why would i split into two parts when i generalize the computation to any r ? I did do it like $\int_0^1$ and $\int_1^r$  but it did not make any difference, the answer was always (e^r^3) - 1

Comment: @Deniz The answer will not be as simple as you seem to suggest.  Even for the special case that Spenser was analyzing the integral gets split upon interchanging the order of integration.  Inasmuch as $e^{y^3}$ has no simple anti-derivative (see the answer provided by Dmoreno), one is left with integration of the incomplete Gamma function.  Of course, there might be some other way to do this.

Comment: @Spenser After conferring with the OP, the lower  limit is $\sqrt{x/3}$. I took the liberty of editing  your answer, which is now correct.  I hope that you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Maybe the result:

$$\int \exp{y^p} \, \mathrm{d} x = \frac{ \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{p},-y^p\right)}{p} = -\frac{y E_{\frac{p-1}{p}}\left(-y^p\right)}{p}, \quad p \neq 0,$$ where $E_i$ is the exponential integral and $\Gamma$ is the incomplete gamma function; is of any help.

Comment: Sorry, but i dont know the Γ symbol and what is actually means. I didn't learn anything like that, yet.

Comment: @Deniz As Dmoreno stated, $\Gamma$ is the [Incomplete Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) function.